# Can And Object Be Controlled By Multiple Classes? (and how to stop this happening)

Tags: java, class, object

I have a Point object that holds coordinates, I then use that Point in the creation of two other objects, a Triangle and a Circle, then inside circle object I translate that point. It also translates the point in the triangle class. Why is this? Have I just set up two variables to access the same object rather than have a 'copy' of that object in both shapes? How can I amend this?

I create the point in the main class then pass that point onto the constructors of both the Circle and Triangle classes which then assign it to a property of that class.

So it's like this:

```
//main class
Point p = new Point(50,50);
Circle c = new Circle(p);
Triangle t = new Triangle(p);

c.translate(20,30); //also translates the triangles point

//Circle class
public Circle(Point p) {
    this.p = p;
}


//Triangle class
public Triangle(Point p) {
    this.p = p;
}
```

Comment: and what is the exact your problem with that?

Comment: As long as your Point is immutable, I think it is actually a good idea that the same Point is shared by all classes as much as possible. That is good memory economy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you passed two references to the same Point object to Circle and Triangle.

To avoid this, there are basically two solutions:

- create a copy of the Point object (either before passing it to Triangle and Circle, or in the constructor of those two classes, to make sure they use a different instances)
- make the Point class immutable (all fields final, no setter), to make sure nobody can ever modify a Point. To translate a point, you would then be forced to create a new Point, with new coordinates. This is much safer, because you can't forget to make a copy. The immutability guarantees that the point can be shared between shapes without any way for them to modify each other by modifying their points.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to copy the object, I'm following a strict spec >.>

Answer (score 1):

The constructors for both your `Circle` and `Triangle` classes just assign the `Point` they are given to a data member. In this way, you're storing a reference to the same object, and every time it's manipulated, it will effect all references to it.

A safer way of handling such situations is, as you suggested, to copy the object passed to the constructor. E.g.:

```
//Circle class
public Circle(Point p) {
    this.p = new Point(p.getX(), p.getY());
}
```

Alternatively, if you defined `Point` as `clonable`:

```
//Circle class
public Circle(Point p) {
    this.p = p.clone();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've heard cloning objects should be avoided though?

Comment: `clone()` has odd semantics, true. Personally, I try to avoid it, but some frameworks/projects employ it. I guess it's a matter of style.

Answer (score 0):

Your making one instance of the Point object and making references to that one Point object in the Circle and Triangle object instances. The translate method modifies that Point object.